# Debugging with python3.5 in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-3.5

I need to reproduce an old setup using Python 3.5,
I'm trying to make it work in VS Code with WSL. I installed python 3.5 using tarball. I downgraded the python extension to v2020.8.109390, I downgraded the python debugger to v2023.1.12071007 and Pylance to v2022.1.0.
These version s should be compatible with python 3.5. Somehow it still doesn't work and I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolveEnvironment'".
Python 3.10 with updated python extensions works(debugs) perfectly. So I guess the error must be something between VSCode extensions and python3.5. I just don't know what to look for or check to solve this problem.

Comment: why Python v3.5, what bugs do you need to be present